# Magento 2 How to combine custom module JS in one JS file?

Tags: magento2, javascript, custom, jquery

I have multiple modules installed on my website, all modules have scripts in phtml file. I need to move that all scripts into one JS file so it can reduce the page size and merged them as a JS file.

I did in require-js

```
map: {
        '*': {
            'mergescript':'Magento_Theme/js/mergescript'
        }
    }
```

then in phmtl file called

```
require([ "jquery", 'mergescript'], function($, mergescript) {
    mergescriptJs();
});
```

then in the mergescript.js file

```
define(['jquery','lazyLoad','bootstrap','jquery/ui'], function($){
        "use strict";
        return function mergescriptJs()
        { alert('Test'); }
    });
```

**it showing an error in the console as "mergescriptJs" is not defined.**

Answer (score 0):

Add like below in your **requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        'mergescript':'Magento_Theme/js/mergescript'
    } ,
    shim: {
        'mergescript': {
            'deps': ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

**After run the below commands,**

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:f
```

Comment: Thanks, @madani I did the same but still the same error I got. I can see the js file in the network. also, update the question. please check and let me know if anything,

Comment: did you run the magento commands ??

Answer (score 0):

```
require([ "jquery", 'mergescript'], function($, mergescript) {
    mergescriptJs();
});
```

You are importing `mergescript` but trying to invoke `mergescriptJS()`.

Does `mergescript()` work for you?

If not try changing `mergescript.js` to:

```
define(['jquery','lazyLoad','bootstrap','jquery/ui'], function($){
        "use strict";
        return function() { 
            alert('Test');
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please to use it in this way

```
require([ "jquery", 'mergescript'], function($) {
   // mergescriptJs(); // remove this
});
```

Then

```
define(['jquery','lazyLoad','bootstrap','jquery/ui'], function($){
    "use strict";
    
    function mergescriptJs(){ 
       alert('Test');
    }
        
    // To see alert
    mergescriptJs();

    // call all other function like click and all
});
```

This is a way I use to load js file

Happy coding

Comment: Thanks, @Nilesh Dubey. It may be useful but I need to call this file in multiple phtml as I need to merge the script written in all phtml files into the single Js file. I think it will load multiple times when I call it on each phtml file.

Comment: Ok then call mergescriptJs directly in phtml as you where calling before I think that will work. Only make sure your js file get load in browser